# Primefaces PickList Ajax transfer event not firing

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces, picklist

I'm using primefaces components in my projects.

My question is about the pickList component.

```
<p:pickList>
  <p:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{rotaBean.operacao}" update="msg frequencia" process="pickList" partialSubmit="true"
         oncomplete="if (args.validationFailed){ PF('periodoColeta').hide();} else{ PF('periodoColeta').show();}" />
</p:pickList>
```

When I have a lot of items in source list in pickList the transfer event ajax is not called.

Source list have approximately 2000 items.

Why does it happen?

Help me please.

I asked the question in the community of primefaces yesterday.

[Primefaces Community](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=49540&p=152683#p152683)

Can someone help me please.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested your code, but would think the problem is that the `p:pickList` processes both all sources and all targets on submit, which means the converter run for all the entities, and if that means calling the database for each entity it takes a long time.

If you find a way to avoid processing the source list you will run into other problems keeping the lists in both the dom and backing bean in sync (at least I did), for example if an error happens.

If this is the problem the easiest solution I found was to use the  [OmniFaces ListConverter](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/ListConverter). It works really great. But whether that will be fast enough for converting everything on every single transfer I don't know.

Comment: I'm just processing the AJAX transfer event.

Comment: You have process="pickList" so it will process it

Comment: Only Source items are submitted to my Bean.

Comment: Only the items that are sent to the target are submitted to the server.

Comment: In my Bean: `public void operacao(final TransferEvent event) throws Exception { event.getItems(); ...} `

Comment: Do you have a converter for the entity?

Comment: `event.getItems();` Grab all the submitted items.

Comment: Once more, do you have a converter for the entity?

Comment: Yeah! I have a converter.

Comment: Then make a system.out in the getAsObject method, then you will know for sure if it processes everything